# Socket.io - Prevent server crash if "client" emit wrong data

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sockets, socket.io

Currently im working on a project using node.js and socket.io.

If wonder if there is any way to automatically validate data the client emitted to the server. I don't want to validate the data by using `if (!...) return;` for each variable I want to use in the ongoing function.

for example I have the following code on **server.js**

```
socket.on('haveData', function(data) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1', [data.userid], function(errData, results, fields) {
        if (!errData && results.length) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

but **now**, if I type `socket.emit('haveData');` in the console of my browser, the socket.io server is crashing - sure, there is no data emitted

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userid' of undefined
```

Comment: Either you check the client data before it got sent, either you check the received data in the server. No other choice here, but you will definitely have `if (!...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Joi https://github.com/hapijs/joi.

Joi allows you to  define schema for input data and validate it with Joi.validate method (Example : https://github.com/hapijs/joi#example).

Socket.on('event',function(data,callback){}) accepts a callback function, it can be used to pass the error message back to client.

Example code :

```
const Joi = require('joi');

socket.on('data',function(data,callback){

    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        userid : Joi.string().trim().required()
    })

    Joi.validate(data, schema, function (err, value) {
        if(err){
            //Error will be sent back to the client who emitted the event
            callback(err)
        }else{
            //Do  your stuff 
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks interesting. So with Joi I can define that the data sent to the server **can** contain "userid, message, token, ..." for example and inside the shema I can say that userid hast to be an integer always and message has to be a string with a maximum length of 50 chars.. and if the requirements in the sent data are not equal to the shema I can send an error back to the client and the server do not "crash"? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Joi has a very nice API for validating inputs. You should check it out.

Comment: You will also want to make sure that callback is a function. You can do this with Joi in the schema like `callback: Joi.function().required()` or with js by doing `if(callback && typeof callback == 'function')`

Answer (score 1):

Server-side code MUST validate all data sent from the client.  You simply cannot ever fully trust a client because clients can be modified/hacked or even a rogue client could connect to your server.

In this particular case, all you should need to fix that particular issue is this `if (data && data.userid)` to check what you are being sent:

```
socket.on('haveData', function(data) {
    if (data && data.userid) {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1', [data.userid], function(errData, results, fields) {
            if (!errData && results.length) {
                ...
            }

        });
     } else {
         // send some error back or just ignore the faulty request
     }
});
```

If you really wanted to be cautious, you could even use:

```
if (data && data.userid && typeof data.userid === "string")
```

This makes sure that `data` exists, that `data.userid` exists and is not an empty string and that `data.userid` is a string.